# Foreign Characters become Auto bold in iOS google chrome / Mac Safari

Tags: css, safari, google-font-api, mobile-chrome

The problem I am facing is depicted here in this image - [image: in this image]

As you can see, the foreign characters become auto bold. I spent some time looking for the solution but this is all I could find - http://www.cryoutcreations.eu/forums/t/incorrect-display-of-special-characters.

The problem replicates in mobile google chrome and also on mac safari but renders fine (all text with uniform weight) on Mac google chrome.

EDIT:
The problem can be seen live here - http://respectvn.townhallapp.io/vi/c%C3%A2u-h%E1%BB%8Fi/63/k%E1%BA%BFt-qu%E1%BA%A3

Comment: Which font is that exactly? If the characters aren't actually available in the font you're using then it will automatically fallback to a google sans-serif or other font that includes them. Also, do you have any css influencing your fonts anywhere?

Comment: @ChrisW., thanks for your reply. The web link is http://respectvn.townhallapp.io/vi/câu-hỏi/63/kết-quả .  It is using Open Sans font.

Comment: @ChrisW., if it is a characters unsupported by font issue, then how it renders fine on Mac Google Chrome?

Comment: I can only assume if that were the case, that mac google's chrome fallback font must be similar enough to the one you're using it's not noticed. Or perhaps the mobile side only includes a minimal version of the font not including all foreign characters perhaps? Hard to tell without tinkering with it personally. Your link is 404. Do you provide the font via `@font-face` declaration with url to the fonts directly, or simply reference them like `font-family: blah, blah, blah`?

Comment: @ChrisW. , the link is http://respectvn.townhallapp.io/vi/c%C3%A2u-h%E1%BB%8Fi/63/k%E1%BA%BFt-qu%E1%BA%A3. My poor knowledge of CSS is a challenge for me. As to your question, this is what i see while inspecting element:
@ font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}

Comment: Add that info to your question please so it's readable. I have to run for meetings and stuff, will try to circle back later.

Comment: @ChrisW., done. Thank you.